# Unix Performance testing - training content

Tags: performance, training

My company is involved with performing performance testing and now they want to perform couple of training related with executing those tests on the servers based on Unix systems.

We will test aplications that are set on the unix server so this training should provide for us information that will be useful for carry on those tests, how to set up monitoring (sar, vmstat...) how to grather data, how to get remote access and so on.
(This training should not have information about performance testing itself - what kind of test, for what is this test etc. only information about carry on those test on Unix servers)

I have to provide them draft of the content for those trainings. In my opinion those trainings should cover:

1. Set up monitoring on the unix servers for main resources:
   CPU Utilization
   Interrupts
   Context Switching
   Memory
   Paging
   Swapping
   Disk I/O
   Network I/O
2. Collecting the Data
3. Remote access to Unix server (put/get data, which application use and so one...)

Is there anything else what we can add to this training that will be useful for us?

Answer (score 1):

How about making sure everyone understands the impact of each item, for example how would it affect performance if there are "too many" interrupts, and how many is too many?, I know swapping is bad, but how much swapping is bad? maybe set up some marks at company level or ranges would help